# write hql query for retrieving records based on character identifier by using where clause

Tags: sql, database, hibernate, select, hql

In hibernate programme am trying to write a hqlquery as shown below.

```
String query = "select amount from info.amount.AmountVO where username="
               + objLdto.getUsername();
```

`getUsername()` returns string value. But in the DB column datatype is `varchar2`.

So the query sent to DB is `select amount........ where username=balu ;`

Here I am getting  null value because the value is treated as normal string.I want to make sure that value as character.

How can i do that? And how can i make the value as characcter and how can i add to the above string?

Answer (score 1):

You should never use concatenation to pass parameters to a query. Use parameters:

```
String hql = "select amount from info.amount.AmountVO where username = :name";
Query query = session.createQuery(hql);
query.setString("name", objLdto.getUsername());
```

[Relevant documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#objectstate-querying-executing-parameters).